# COMPLETE pragma doesn't prevent incomplete-patterns warning

Tags: haskell, ghc

I made two pattern views for a list-like class.

```
infixr 5 :<
pattern (:<) :: Stream s => Token s -> s -> s
pattern b :< bs <- (uncons -> Just (b, bs))
  where b :< bs = cons b bs

pattern Nil :: Stream s => s
pattern Nil <- (uncons -> Nothing)
  where Nil = empty
```

`uncons` signature: `uncons :: (Stream s) => s -> Maybe (Token s, s)`.

Suppose I also have function that uses these patterns like that:

```
foo (b:<bs) = …
foo Nil = …
```

It's obvious in this case that pattern matches are exhaustive, and I would like to specify that.

So I tried using a [COMPLETE pragma](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/pattern-synonyms/complete-sigs) like that: `{-# COMPLETE Nil, (:<) :: Stream #-}`.

That didn't work, warning didn't go anywhere. Why didn't it? Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: For reference, the official documentation for the extension is here: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#complete-pragmas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COMPLETE` pragmas can only be attached to types, not type classes. There is currently no way to specify a complete set of patterns that works for all types of a given class.

Comment: Does my attempt have any effect whatsoever? What does it do for type classes if anything?

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure, that in my example `foo` is total. How do I get rid of the warnings? Maybe there is a pragma that disables some specific warnings for a specific function?

Comment: That pragma does nothing, it would be better if GHC warned about it. Disabling certain warnings such as incomplete matches locally is a regularly requested feature, but for now there is no way. You have to rewrite your program differently or disable the warning globally (at least for the whole file).