# Haskell, PatternSynonyms, COMPLETE pragma, and View Patterns

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a class, `SeqNE`, representing non-empty Sequences:

```
newtype SeqNE α = SeqNE { unSeqNE ∷ NonNull (Seq α) }
  deriving Eq

type instance Element (SeqNE α) = α
```

where `NonNull` is from Michael Snoyman's [mono-traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.1/docs/Data-NonNull.html) package, and `Sequence` is from the [containers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) package.

I have a (unicode) pattern to (de)compose `SeqNE` instances:

```
infixl 5 :⫸
{- | (de)compose a `SeqNE α` from a `Seq α` and an `α` (rightwards) -}
pattern (:⫸) ∷ Seq α -> α -> SeqNE α
pattern xs :⫸ x <- (unsnoc -> (xs,x))
  where xs :⫸ x = xs ||> x
{-# COMPLETE (:⫸) #-}
```

where `unsnoc` has type `unsnoc ∷ SeqNE α → (Seq α, α)`.

As shown, I have used the [`COMPLETE` pragma](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/pattern-synonyms/complete-sigs) to tell GHC that this pattern is total.
However, in practice, if I use such a pattern match within a view pattern (e.g., `foo`, below); then I am rewarded with a "Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive" warning; whereas, if I use what I believe is morally the same code, but within an explicit case statement (e.g., `bar`, below), then the warning is elided (I have tested removing the `COMPLETE` pragma, and as expected, I then get the warning with `bar` also).

```
foo ∷ NonEmpty.NonEmpty α → Seq α
foo (fromNonEmpty → xs :⫸ _) = xs

bar ∷ NonEmpty.NonEmpty α → Seq α
bar ss = case fromNonEmpty ss of
           xs :⫸ _ → xs
```

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401723/complete-pragma-doesnt-prevent-incomplete-patterns-warning), but the answer to that was that `COMPLETE` is ineffectual for type /classes/; I'm not using a typeclass here.

So I think this may be a legit. bug with GHC, `COMPLETE` pragmas. vs. view-patterns - but I'd like a second (and third) opinion, as I tend to be wrong a lot more often than GHC is...

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Sounds like you are on older ghc (possibly ghc-8.2), cause ghc-8.4 onward I haven't seen this particular issue. So, my question is what's your ghc version?

Comment: @lehins - good point!  This is with ghc-8.6.5 .

Comment: @user3416536 From your description it does look like it is a ghc bug, but you don't paint the full picture:

* what is the definition of `unsnoc`?
* where `||>` comes from and what is its definition?
* what is the actual error and the reported missing pattern?

In any case, have you tried replacing the unicode character with some common ascii allowed with infix, I would not be surprised that unicode is tripping something up up. Also could be worth switching to a regular function instead of an infix operator, just as an extra debugging step.